# Do not work SQL request for changing datetime by default

Tags: mysql, datetime

In database table I need to change default value (that is already created) of **`datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`** on **`datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'`**. All attempts to change failed.

Created default value by using **`CREATE TABLE`**:

**`'post_date' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`**

My requests:

**`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER post_date SET DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'`**

**`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date SET DEFAULT datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()`**

**`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`**

**`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT NULL`**
и тд.

Got Errors:
**`Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'post_date'`**

What result I need to get: **`datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'`**

Comment: Made the translation

Comment: `datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is already **invalid**. I doubt you could create a table with such field*

Comment: It is already created, and I need to change somehow

Comment: Try removing the default value `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER post_date DROP DEFAULT;` then re-add it using your new default value: `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER post_date SET DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'`